# I use Yahoo in Chrome for email. How can I change Outlook from auto-starting?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook

My main email account is Yahoo. Whenever I click an email address in a website, it auto-starts Outlook. Can I configure Chrome to open a "compose message" window with that email address auto-filled at Yahoo.com instead of Outlook opening? My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Chrome extension [Email Links To Yahoo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-links-to-yahoo-mail/ldmnopcabfcfhgflmlgibifpmcbejbjb).

> Clicking on an email link will open up Yahoo email compose page.

Comment: The author uses Yahoo not gmail.  I am sure there is a chrome/firefox/ie extensions for this behavior though

Comment: ah good point I have edited my answer with a more relavant extension

Comment: Because you made the edit I have given this answer an upvote.